# Wrong space with \footnotemark

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I am using `\footnotemark`, but the space after the mark is smaller than the space I obtain when I use regular `\footnote`.  How can I obtain the usual space after `\footnote`?  See example below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

Phrase. Standard without footnote.

Phrase.\footnote{foot1}
With footnote.

Phrase.\footnotemark\ %
Smaller with footnotemark;
how can I correct it?
\footnotetext{foot2}

Phrase.\footnotemark
Definitively wrong.
\footnotetext{foot3}

\end{document}
```

Edit:  Thanks for all the answers.  I will accept the first one, and vote the rest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An empty group `{}` after the `\footnotemark` seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
Phrase. Standard without footnote.

Phrase.\footnote{foot1}
With footnote.

Phrase.\footnotemark{}
Smaller with footnotemark;
how can I correct it?
\footnotetext{foot2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The definition of `\footnotemark` essentially does as follows:

1. Compute the footnote number
2. Start LR mode (we want to be inside a paragraph)
3. Save the current "space factor"
4. Don't break a line here
5. Print the footnote mark
6. Restore the space factor that was saved

However, `\`  inserts the amount of space that would be inserted when the space factor is 1000 (by rule), so the space factor that was saved is ignored with

```
end of the phrase.\footnotemark\ Text that follows ...
```

This doesn't happen with

```
end of the phrase.\footnotemark{} Text that follows ...
```

as `{}` gets ignored and doesn't influence the space factor computations.

Even if DEK tells that `\`  is OK after a text producing control sequence in mid paragraph, I usually recommend terminating them with `{}`.

If one says `\frenchspacing` and ignores all the business about the space factor and "double spaces after periods", then such problems wouldn't arise.

Answer (score 8):

After `\footnote{}`, TeX sets the newline as if it were a normal space. With `\footnotemark`, the newline gets gobbled. Your intuition was right in making the space explicit using `\` , but the problem is that `\`  is *not* exactly the same as a normal space – it also overrides how TeX adds extra space at the end of sentences.

So the solution is to use `\footnotemark{}` or `{\footnotemark}`. That way, TeX doesn't gobble the space in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

instead of inserting a control space

```
Phrase.\footnotemark\ %
```

use a null group so that tex will

```
Phrase.\footnotemark{}
```

do the "right thing" with the space following a period.